# Comparing dataframe to list and updating dataframe based on list data comparison

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, text, string-comparison

I am trying to compare text in a dataframe column to an existing list and then update a new column in the dataframe based on the comparison. The text in the dataframe column is more complex than in the list. If the dataframe text contains the text from the list, I would like the take the list value and update the new dataframe column. I have tried a for-loop for this but I get an error that my iterator isn't an integer. Below are definitions and my code.

myDF is the data frame
Product is the column I would like to assess
makelist is the list of strings I would like to compare myDF.Product against
If there is a match, I want to update myDF.Brand.

When I run the following I get an error that says I am indexing with an invalid variable type.

```
import pandas as pd
myDF = pd.DataFrame({"Location": 'S1 S1 S1 S1 S1'.split(),
                    "Product": '12AB 34CD 56EF 78GH 90IJ'. split(),
                    "Brand": ""})
makelist = ['12A', '4CD', '56', '78G', '90IJ']

for items in myDF.Product:
    for makes in makelist:
        if makelist[makes] in(myDF.Product.iloc[items]):
            myDF.Brand[items]=makelist[makes]

#expected output
Location Product Brand
0       S1    12AB   12A
1       S1    34CD   4CD
2       S1    56EF    56
3       S1    78GH   78G
4       S1    90IJ  90IJ
```

Comment: `myDF['Brand'] = myDF.loc[myDF['Product'].isin(makelist), 'Product']`?

Comment: could you show expected output for this dataframe?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: The error you are getting is caused by the indexing in `makelist[makes]` since you are trying to access a list using a string, and not a (numeric) index.
Similarly, you cannot index by location index with a non-integer key in `myDF.Product.iloc[items]`

Comment: @FBruzzesi, does this mean I need to use the '.index' to iterate as I intended? What I don't understand is when I run the for loops separately, they both work fine.

Comment: @ansev, your suggestion seemed to only grab the complete matches. I am trying to find if the text in myDF contains the material from makelist and if it does, update Brand with the matching item from makelist.

Answer (score 0):

Here two implementations, the first following your idea, the second optimizing using just one for loop.

**Set up**

```py
import pandas as pd
brands = ['12A', '4CD', '56', '78G', '90IJ']
```

**Two for loops**

```py
myDF = pd.DataFrame({"Location": 'S1 S1 S1 S1 S1'.split(),
                    "Product": '12AB 34CD 56EF 78GH 90IJ'. split(),
                    "Brand": ""}) 

for product in myDF['Product']:
    for brand in brands:
        if brand in product:
            myDF.loc[myDF['Product']==product, 'Brand'] = brand

myDF
  Location Product Brand
0       S1    12AB   12A
1       S1    34CD   4CD
2       S1    56EF    56
3       S1    78GH   78G
4       S1    90IJ  90IJ
```

**One for loop**

```py
myDF = pd.DataFrame({"Location": 'S1 S1 S1 S1 S1'.split(),
                    "Product": '12AB 34CD 56EF 78GH 90IJ'. split(),
                    "Brand": ""})     

for brand in brands:
    myDF.loc[myDF['Product'].str.contains(brand), 'Brand'] = brand

myDF
  Location Product Brand
0       S1    12AB   12A
1       S1    34CD   4CD
2       S1    56EF    56
3       S1    78GH   78G
4       S1    90IJ  90IJ
```